# How does BER compare between different 10GbE physical media?

Tags: networking, ethernet, 10gbethernet, sfp

I am under the impression that you should use optical for 10GbE networking because of a BER (bit error rate) several orders of magnitude lower than copper.

I'm pretty sure I previously found documentation stating so, but for the life of me I just cannot find it.

I'd like to see documentation on typical BER (in general, if such a thing exists) for:

- 10GBase-T ports (with Cat6a cabling)
- 10GBase-CX4 ports
- 10GBase-T SFP+ modules (Cat6a cabling)
- Fiber SFP+ SR modules
- DAC SFP+ modules

Comment: I think distance and cost requirements may factor into your decision matrix as well.

Comment: BER by itself is a meaningless metric when comparing technologies. It only has meaning when comparing the same product from different vendors. By the way: Copper SFP+ is misleading: These are eiter 10Gbase-T or Twinax (which is the same as DAC).

Comment: Distance and cost requirements will factor into the overall decision, yes, but the purpose behind this question is to gain insight into the BER of various media.

Comment: BER is absolutely -not- meaningless.  There is a two order of magnitude difference between twisted pair and twinax.  This is why, for example, FCoE isn't supported on 10GBaseT yet.

Comment: Great! Can you please provide documentation?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/195111/why-would-i-choose-copper-over-sfp-for-10gbe?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

Twinax is rated at 10^-17 at <= 10M

Fiber is generally 10^-18 or better (lot of variables here, though - especially on long haul)

Ethernet's minimum specification is 10^-12.  This is where the contention comes in as far as FC goes - it may be that a TP infrastructure can support better than 10^-12 (and hopefully most do) but at 10G speeds even that much error translates to a bad packet every few minutes.

Comment: [*The long-term prognosis forFCoE over 10GBaseT looks very promising*](http://sniaesfblog.org/?p=139)

Comment: Yes - absolutely.  Smaller die sizes mean DSP's are improving, which improves BER and power issues.  Moore's law works for more than just CPU's!  I wouldn't be surprised if we saw movement in this regard in the next 12 months.